# Docker networking with several network adapters

Tags: docker, networking, docker-compose, windows-server-2019

I have a windows server. There are 2 network adapters:

```
Ethernet adapter tapf2a27fa9-4e:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::2467:x:c982:f97a%16
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 172.16.0.26
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.252
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 172.16.0.25

Ethernet adapter tap15be2ea1-26:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::e02d:x:a5bc:e93a%8
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : x.x.229.205
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.248
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : x.x.229.201
```

The second one is public.

I'm trying to run react app in docker container. When I run it, it is accessable locally (RDP) (means I can reach it on `localhost:80`). But when I'm trying to access it from my local machine `x.x.229.205:80`, it cannot make connection (timeout). So, what's the problem?

Here my Dockerfile and docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  front-prod:
    container_name: front-prod
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - '80:80'
```

```
FROM node:16-alpine3.17 as build
WORKDIR /app
ENV PATH /app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH
COPY package.json ./
COPY package-lock.json ./
RUN npm ci --silent
RUN npm install react-scripts@3.4.1 -g --silent
COPY . ./
RUN npm run build

FROM nginx:stable-alpine
COPY --from=build /app/build /usr/share/nginx/html
COPY nginx/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
EXPOSE 80
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

I tried to make redirection of traffic from my public network adapter to local, but it didn't help (or I made it wrong)

Answer (score 0):

You should change

```yaml
version: '3.7'

services:
  front-prod:
    container_name: front-prod
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - '80:80'
```

into (reoplace `x.x` with your own)

```yaml
version: '3.7'

services:
  front-prod:
    container_name: front-prod
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - '172.16.0.26:80:80/tcp'
      - 'x.x.229.205:80:80/tcp'
```

Comment: Why does this help?  I would expect Docker's default to be to listen on all host interfaces; the main thing I'd expect this to do is to prevent `http://localhost` from working (because the container is no longer listening on host 127.0.0.1).